# backtick character to use variable in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to use backtick character to create my text but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```js
import Speech from 'react-speech';

<Speech text= `${pokemon.name} test` lang="EN-US" pitch="2" rate="0.70"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's a magic quote but if you want to pass a dynamic prop, try this:

```
<Speech text={`${pokemon.name} test`} lang="EN-US" pitch="2" rate="0.70"/>
```

`{}` can also be used for variables.